# attempt at a nested functions

Tags: python, function, printing, nested, return

fair to say I'm newish to python. I'm trying to get my head around nested functions however I can't manage to get the output that I want. I want my IQ_multiplier function to return me IQ scores that have been put through the clever_multiplier, followed by the string "with multiplier".
e.g 158.4 , "with multiplier"
72 , "with multiplier"
etc..

...However, my first attempt keeps giving me the multiplier score without the string while my second attempt gives me both the multiplier score and the string but stops at the first score. I understand that there are probably easier ways of executing the output I'm tryna get (without nested functions) however I'm tryna understand what is wrong with both my attempts at nested functions. Thanks

```
IQ = [132, 92, 75, 97, 118]
def IQ_multiplier(IQ):
     def clever_multiplier(IQ):
        for val in IQ:
         if val > 100:
            return val * 1.2
         else:
            return val - 20
     return (clever_multiplier(IQ), "with multiplier")
print(IQ_multiplier(IQ))



IQ = [132, 92, 75, 97, 118]
def IQ_multiplier(IQ):
     def clever_multiplier(IQ):
        for val in IQ:
         if val > 100:
            print (val * 1.2)
         else:
            print (val - 20)
     return (clever_multiplier(IQ), "with multiplier")
print(IQ_multiplier(IQ))
```

Comment: In your first attempt, you're calling `clever_multiplier` on a list, but returning immediately on the first iteration.  I suspect you are actually intending to call `clever_multiplier` on each element of the list, rather than on the entire list.  The for loop needs to be part of the outer function, not the inner function.    For the second one, your inner function is just printing, but returning None.  So your result will be none.  Again, you probably want the for loop in the outer function, not the inner one.

Answer (score 0):

I made a thing which is not good educationally...

```
def IQ_multiplier(IQs=None):
    if not hasattr(IQ_multiplier, 'IQs'):
        IQ_multiplier.IQs = []
    if IQs is None and len(IQ_multiplier.IQs) != 0:
        val = IQ_multiplier.IQs.pop(0)
        if val > 100:
            return (val * 1.2, 'with multiplier')
        else:
            return (val - 20, 'with multiplier')
    elif IQs is None and len(IQ_multiplier.IQs) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        IQ_multiplier.IQs.extend(IQs)
```